# Should the values of html elements with "display: none;" be returned by HtmlUnit

Tags: htmlunit

Given the following table, where every other row has it `display` value set to `none`:

```
    <table>
        <thead>
        <tr><th>Expand</th><th>Some Id</th><th>Some Attribute</th><th>Another Attribute</th></tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr><td><a href="#" onclick="expandRow('101')">V</a></td><td>101</td><td>fast</td><td>1/1/1</td></tr>
            <tr style="display: none"><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>A Hidden Value 1011</td></tr>
            <tr><td><a href="#" onclick="expandRow('102')">V</a></td><td>102</td><td>fast</td><td>2/2/2</td></tr>
            <tr style="display: none"><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>2</td><td>A Hidden Value 1022</td></tr>
            <tr><td><a href="#" onclick="expandRow('103')">V</a></td><td>103</td><td>fast</td><td>3/3/3</td></tr>
            <tr style="display: none"><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>3</td><td>A Hidden Value 1033</td></tr>
            <tr><td><a href="#" onclick="expandRow('104')">V</a></td><td>104</td><td>fast</td><td>4/4/4</td></tr>
            <tr style="display: none"><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>4</td><td>A Hidden Value 1044</td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

When I use HtmlUnit with an xPath expression to retrieve all the rows:

```
   HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://localhost:4567/Home.html");
   List<HtmlTableRow> rowsByXPath = page.getByXPath("//tbody/tr");
```

all of the rows are retrieved, however even though the rows that have their `display` value set to `none` are retrieved, the value of their cells are not available when using `asText`.

As an example if I attempt to print the values for the final cell in each row using the following code:

```
cells.forEach(cell -> System.err.print("[" + cell.asText() + "]"));
```

The output is:

```
[1/1/1][][2/2/2][][3/3/3][][4/4/4][]
```

However when I use `asXml`:

```
cells.forEach(cell -> System.err.print("[" + cell.asXml() + "]"));
```

The following output is obtained (modified for readability):

```
[<td>1/1/1</td>][<td>A Hidden Value 1011</td>]
[<td>2/2/2</td>][<td>A Hidden Value 1022</td>]
[<td>3/3/3</td>][<td>A Hidden Value 1033</td>]
[<td>4/4/4</td>][<td>A Hidden Value 1044</td>]
```

Is this the expected behaviour?

I expected the output from using the `asText` on the cells to be:

```
[1/1/1][A Hidden Value 1011][2/2/2][A Hidden Value 1022][3/3/3][A Hidden Value 1033][4/4/4][A Hidden Value 1044]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XPath is an XML feature and works without any HTML semantics. This implies that style attributes are not hiding any element from the tree.

Or the other way around - it is correct that you find the (hidden) elements when using XPath.

On the other hand methods like DomNode.asText() are working on the DOM tree in an HTML context - asText will return an empty string if the node is not visible.

Comment: If I understand correctly if the elements are in the XML tree their associated values should be too?

Comment: Yes. Please make your problem a bit more clear by adding some code and your expectations.

Comment: I think you have grasped the issue perfectly; that said I will attempted to update the question with some code and to clarify my expectations as it sounds like they are once more out of alignment with reality :)

Comment: I have attempted to clarify my question, and provide a better example and explanation of what I had expected.